# Firebase Authentication long loading time to verify user | Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication

I have a react application using firebase authentication. I have a global context that handles all functionality around the currently logged in user. This is my useEffect in said context:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribeAuth = firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(handleUser);
    const unsubscribeToken = firebase.auth.onIdTokenChanged(handleUser);
    return () => {
        unsubscribeAuth();
        unsubscribeToken();
    };
}, []);
```

I have a `<ProtectedRoute/>` component that checks if the user is logged in. When I visit a protected route it's loading for quite some time, around **5 seconds** before rendering the actual page.

**ProtectedRoute component**

```js
function ProtectedRoute({ children }: Props) {
    const router = useRouter();
  
    const auth = useAuth();

    if (auth.loading) { // Still loading (around 5 seconds!)
        return ( <Spinner/>)    
    }
    if (auth.user) {
        // Accepted -> render children
        return children;
    } else {
        // Redirect to sign in
        router.push("/sign-in");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to make this check way faster?

It takes around 0.5s if the user has not been logged in before, so I assume the reason it takes a long time is that firebase is confirming the saved token by making a request somewhere. But it shouldn't take that long, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember that I ran to the same problem and it was because of trying to get the token while the user is not authentificated yet. If it's the case you should verify first if the user is authentificated then try to recieve the token.